# The purpose of loading External Javascript of social media into webpages

Tags: javascript, performance, social-networking, html

When adding social media resources in webpage, the traditional method results in loading much external JS from other domains, just to load an iframe or an anchor with a brand image background. Probably the below are the most transferred files over the web   (after the http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js 36.35KB, which is somehow inevitable for many)

http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js 181.30KB (59.06KB gzipped)
https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js 75.19KB (24.42KB gzipped)
https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js 16.71KB
http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js (well this is small, but still unneeded connection)

> For example, http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js does only one
>   thing: adding an iFrame `<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Flavishdream&amp;width=292&amp;height=180&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=true&amp;border_color&amp;stream=false&amp;header=false" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:292px; height:180px;" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>`
>
> Twitter and Google Plus scripts does very similar tasks, only adding
>   small HTML chunks into the page.

Why not only writing those iFrames, images and anchors HTML ?

Comment: more suitable for webmasters.stackexchange.com?

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question, if you are using any of those libraries to enhance your site, you will nee to load them.

Comment: @KevinDTimm I think this  is something a developer should answer, maybe there's Javascript dependency in some situations, etc...

Comment: @KevinDTimm furthermore I sow similar questions there at webmasters that was migrated here or to serverfault

Comment: @AntLaC Okay thanks I will edit the question adding more details.

Comment: @AntLaC edited text enclosed within blockquotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of those scripts you've mentioned are also tracking the users behavior in the background. Also, when loading a JS file the provider (e.g. Google) could change the functionality that comes with such a script. This wouldn't be that easy when you just add a static file or write the desired HTML yourself.

Comment: 1+ for the custom behaviour according to the layout. However this page http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Flavishdream&width=292&height=180&colorscheme=light&show_faces=true&border_color&stream=false&header=false will just fit well in a static written iframe, won't it?

Comment: @rahmanisback Yes it is. What I tried to say is, that the reason for so much JS is not a technical one; but a economical one. It's all about user tracking and earning money with your clients personal data. That's how companies like Facebook or Google get their money. I don't really want to know what else those scripts really do – that would cause privacy nightmares…

Answer (score 0):

It wont interfere with your sites performance. Multiple resources should be loaded by each js and this should not affect the site they are embed.

Comment: sir, adding 70KB of external JS to a small page of 35KB is a waste of bandwidth. and yes I worry about performance in browser and in download time. Not everybody can get a highspeed connection right?

Comment: It might be easy to update latest js like script as service model and also adressing cross browser issues will be easy with this model

Answer (score 0):

The libraries you are referring to are doing a lot more than just adding the simple iFrames. They are also referencing objects within the frames. As far as performance, the only issues you will have is if their sites that are hosting the js files go down.

Comment: I just saw your comment about bandwidth, unfortunately, if you want to use those services, you will have to take into consideration of the js libraries. You can also download a copy of the files to your local server and host them yourself, but be careful if they make any changes, you will have to redownload them, but this really won't improve too much.

Comment: I say, iframes can call whatever JS they need. Nothing is wrong with that. What I say is why we need JS to CREATE those elements?

Comment: I'm sorry you are having trouble with this, I just opened the FB js file and it is doing a lot more than just creating an iframe. Also, the js file needs to be on the local client for it to attach to the contents of the iframe. Another thing, whatever the iframes do affect your bandwidth as well.

Comment: you still didn't get the question, sir. would you open this page? does it look and behave fine in any browser? i can position it as as an iFrame. that's my question. http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Flavishdream&width=292&height=180&colorscheme=light&show_faces=true&border_color&stream=false&header=false

Comment: you are still loading 6 other js files even if you put it in an iframe, and you will STILL be using that bandwidth to load them.

Comment: Also, if you create the iframe, the js file may not recognize it

Answer (score -1):

First of all, any Javascript is a client-side application, so you don't have to worry about the performance needed to layout these components.
Second, these files are very small so the traffic is negligible and even if the iFrames were in HTML you needed some kind of connection to get it, right? Because obviously you can't just put the like-button for example statically in your code (for reasons of maintainability)

Comment: adding 70KB of external JS to a small page of 35KB is a waste of bandwidth. and yes I worry about performance in browser and in download time. Not everybody can get a highspeed connection.